# 'the use of' or 'use of'?

Tags: definite-article, present-tense, clauses

I have two questions. 
1. Should I use article 'the' before 'use of'?
2. Is this sentence fragment grammatically correct?

> Project is aiming to present a method with use of [name] algorithm to ensure ...

Comment: What is the context?  "Bullet points on powerpoint presentations, project plans, and semi-informal emails can drop some elements for sake of being concise." :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- "project" needs an article: **"The project..."**
- "is aiming" should be in the present simple: **"...aims to present a method..."**
- as regards your actual question, I would suggest **"...using the [name] algorithm to ensure..."** or **"...which will use the [name] algorithm to ensure..."**